# Why don't programs on Windows usually add themselves to the PATH variable?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

I couldn't even count the number of times I've had to manually add a directory. Is there a security reason for it, or do developers/installers not think about it?

Comment: Did you _ask_ me to add myself to the PATH? For all users? Even those who don't use the application? How long do you want PATH to get?

Comment: Good point. How does UNIX handle that?

Comment: Big ball of mud.  c:\windows\system32 used to be like that.

Comment: This is what App Paths are for

Comment: UNIX (or at least Linux) puts most executable files the user will probably use in `/bin`, and users and programs usually put files in other folders ending in `/bin`. Many Windows programs seem to have been doing the same recently. The one for MS SQL Server seems to call itself `binn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a program is started via a link, which has the path to the executable hard coded within it. There's no need to add to the general $PATH unless the program will be commonly executed from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

What, exactly, are you trying to do?  Windows, not being a relic of the steam age, has a number of built in features that usually make fooling with the Path environmental variable unnecessary.